# Adding/Deleting into XML in Android

Tags: android, xml

I populate spinners from xml. I want users to add a new item or delete one in my source XML. Is there anyway to achieve this programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not change `resource` files at runtime. You will need to store this information in some type of persistent storage such as:

- SharedPreferences
- An SQLite DB
- To a file
- On a webserver

Its impossible to say which would be best without knowing more about your needs but have a look at [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and see which would be best for your situation.